# sqoop EXPORT - There is no column found in the target table

Tags: export, sqoop

I wrote a simple script to create a user (TestV100), create a table (Xy100) in that schema and export a tabl delimited flat file from hadoop to this oracle table.

### This is the shell script: - ExportOracleTestV100.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Testing connectivity to Oracle DB
#sqoop eval --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:orcl -username test -password password --query "SELECT count(*) as bob FROM \"TestV1\".\"Test\"" --verbose

HOST=$1
USER=$2
PASS=$3
SCHEMA=$4
PORT=$5
SID=$6
SQOOP=/usr/bin/sqoop
JDBC="jdbc:oracle:thin:@$1:$5:$6"
SQOOP_EVAL="$SQOOP eval --connect $JDBC --username $USER --password $PASS --query"

#Create Schema and Tables;
${SQOOP_EVAL} "CREATE USER \"TestV100\" identified by \"password\""
${SQOOP_EVAL} "GRANT CONNECT TO \"TestV100\""
${SQOOP_EVAL} "ALTER USER \"TestV100\" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS"

${SQOOP_EVAL} "DROP TABLE \"TestV100\".\"Xy100\""
${SQOOP_EVAL} "CREATE TABLE \"TestV100\".\"Xy100\"( \"a\" NVARCHAR2(255) DEFAULT NULL, \"x\" NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT NULL, \"y\" NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT NULL )"


############################
## Load Data into tables; ##
############################

SQOOP_EXPORT="/usr/bin/sudo -u hdfs $SQOOP export --connect ${JDBC} --username $USER --password $PASS --export-dir"
${SQOOP_EXPORT} "/tmp/rv/TestV100/xy100.txt" --table "\"\"$SCHEMA\".\"Xy100\"\"" --fields-terminated-by "\t" --input-null-string null -m 1
```

### And this is the input file: - cat /tmp/rv/TestV100/Xy100.txt

```
c       8       3
a       1       4
c       6       1
c       2       0
a       7       7
c       4       2
c       7       5
a       0       0
c       5       6
a       2       2
a       5       5
a       3       6
c       9       7
a       4       1
c       3       4
a       6       3
b       6       5
b       8       7
b       5       1
b       7       3
b       2       4
b       1       0
b       4       6
b       3       2
```

### This is how the shell script is called:

```
sh ./ExportOracleTestV100.sh oracle11 test password TestV100 1521 orcl --verbose
```

Note: 'test' user has full access on TestV100 schema.

### Output:

```
[root@abc-repo-app1 rv]# sh ./ExportOracleTestV100.sh oracle11 test password TestV100 1521 orcl --verbose
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
15/11/02 12:40:07 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5-cdh5.4.1
15/11/02 12:40:07 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
15/11/02 12:40:07 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
15/11/02 12:40:07 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
15/11/02 12:40:07 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
15/11/02 12:40:08 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
15/11/02 12:40:08 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM "TestV100"."xy100" t WHERE 1=0
15/11/02 12:40:08 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no column found in the target table "TestV100"."xy100". Please ensure that your table name is correct.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no column found in the target table "TestV100"."xy100". Please ensure that your table name is correct.
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1658)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:64)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:100)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

As you can see above, Sqoop version is 1.4.5-cdh5.4.1

I somehow managed to get it this far. I see a lot of posting online for sqoop import and this error, and solution is to change the table name to UPPERCASE in the command. But, I am running export. Also, the oracle table HAS to be created with mixed case.

I hope I gave all required information here. Can someone please help or point to some place which can help me get past this error?

Comment: To add more:
If I connect as ‘test’ user and run the exact same command (SELECT t.* FROM “TestV100”.”xy100″ t WHERE 1=0), it works fine from sql developer!. So, I am sure that the user has permissions.

Answer (score 7):

table name in uppercase worked.

sqoop export --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyzx:1569:xyz --username xyz --password xyz --table CIPHADOOPCUSTOMERREPORT --export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/ciprpt.db/dtd_customer_report --input-fields-terminated-by "\t" --input-lines-terminated-by "\n" --verbose -m 8 --input-null-string '\N' --input-null-non-string '\N'

Comment: I think vjender has the right answer. I changed it to upper case and it worked. BTW this seems like a bug of sqoop.

Answer (score 5):

Supply the table name in upper case in the --table argument.
Sounds silly but yeah - works with table name in upper caps.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem because target table for sqoop export was one column short.
Solution:
specify list of columns with `--columns` parameter; or regenerate target table to match schema of the input table.